# JSON.parse, Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, json, request, undefined

So I have a little web socket program that pulls data from a website. Sometimes it reaches the maximum of 6 queries per seconds and when it does it crashes. I put an  if statement to check if the request was received but it doesn't seem to work. The part of the code making all this mayhem goes like this:

```
Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
                if(error) {
                    var flag = 1;
                    return console.dir(error);
                }
                if(flag == 1)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var object = JSON.parse(body);  <-- error points here
                if(!object || !object.data || !object.data.items || typeof object.data.items[0] === 'undefined')
                {
                    return;
                } ...
```

The output error says this:

> undefined:1
>   Too many requests. Please try again later.
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
>
> at JSON.parse ()
>   at Request.get [as _callback] (/home/pi/Desktop/BitBot/test.js:702:23)
>   at Request.self.callback (/home/pi/Desktop/BitBot/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
>   at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
>   at Request. (/home/pi/Desktop/BitBot/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
>   at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
>   at IncomingMessage. (/home/pi/Desktop/BitBot/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
>   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: you are parsing a body-string that is not a json, wrap the parse in try/catch and do like if(error) => bad response

Comment: Use a try/catch statement to catch the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is happening and why

When you reach the Rate limit set by the remote website, it returns the string **"Too many requests. Please try again later."**

As you could tell, this isn't valid JSON. If you try to `JSON.parse()` this string, you will get an error thrown.

```js
let str = "Too many requests. Please try again later.";

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Instead, you should do two things:

### Read `response.statusCode`

First, check which status code is sent on successful requests. Let's say it is 200. You can then add a block that handles status codes that are different from 200:

```
Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    if(response.statusCode != 200){ //200 is the status code on successful requests in this case
        return console.log(response.statusCode+" "+response.body);
    }
    var object = JSON.parse(body);
});
```

From there, you can even check which status code is sent on "Too many requests" responses. Let's assume it is 429, as specified by [RFC 6585](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4).

```
Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    if(response.statusCode != 200){
        if(response.statusCode == 429)
            return console.log("429 Too many requests"); //429 error
        else
            return console.log(response.statusCode+" "+response.body); //some other status code that isn't '200 OK'
    }
    var object = JSON.parse(body);
});
```

### Add a try-catch block around `JSON.parse()`

`JSON.parse()` is a function that will return the JSON object from a String if it is properly formatted, or throw an error otherwise.

It is thus best practices to wrap it in a try-catch block if the string is coming from another website, as you can't tell that the string will be properly formatted in 100% of cases.

Your final code and its error handling, for me, would look like this in the end:

```
Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    if(response.statusCode != 200){
        if(response.statusCode == 429)
            return console.log("429 Too many requests");
        else
            return console.log(response.statusCode+" "+response.body);
    }
    var object;
    try{
        object = JSON.parse(body);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error on parsing string", err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm kinda works, but now I get this error: 
/home/pi/Desktop/BitBot/test.js:697
     return console.log(response.statusCode+" "+response.body);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
    at Request.get [as _callback] (/home/pi/Desktop/BitBot/test.js:697:34)
    at self.callback...

Comment: You most likely did a typo somewhere, if you call `(error, response, body)` and there is no internal `error`, there has to be a `response.statusCode`.